# Kivy app needs to be unfocused and refocused before it responds to input

Tags: python, opengl, kivy

I started using Kivy a few days ago to build a graphical demo of a python program. I'm running this on OSX. I encountered some weird behavior where about half the time the launched Kivy app seems to be very slow - it will not register any clicks or input.

Eventually I realized that the fix for the problem is to unfocus the app by clicking another program, then bringing up the Kivy app again. After doing that, the application runs perfectly for the rest of the time that it is open. I can immediately identify when the program launches like this because the top bar (with the program name and the OSX exit/minimize/fullscreen buttons) is greyed out. The behavior is not consistent; sometimes I will launch the app ten times in a row without it happening, other times it will do this five or six times in a row.

It's not hugely inconvenient for development, but the demo users may not read documentation etc. and I'd like to provide them with a smooth experience instead of this strange bug. If anyone has any ideas for tracking down the cause of the problem and/or resolving it I would love to hear them!

Here's what the status bar looks like when this occurs - it looks exactly like the app is unfocused, but it does not focus when clicked:
[image: Inactive]

Here's what the status bar looks like normally for the active app, after I click to another app and click back:
[image: Active]

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen such an issue reported before, and I can't think what would cause it. How long does the app take to start up, does this ever happen if you make a simple test app that does nothing but (say) display a Label?

Comment: The app takes about three seconds to start (from hitting enter in terminal to having a filled window with everything loaded). I just tried out one with just a label (no .kv file or other python code) and the same issue occurred. While testing that I discovered that the easiest way to replicate the issue is to insert any code in the python and the issue will occur on the next run. Code can be completely unrelated - a declaration of "i=1" did it. Modifying an existing line doesn't do anything, nor does deleting a line. I am completely lost with regard to what this means. I added pictures above.

Comment: So this happens if, and only if, the python source has been changed in any way since the previous run? That's a very strange problem. Are you running via some IDE, or a separate python install?